# Optimize query that takes too much time to be executed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I use the following query in order to calculate the amount for each month as well as the trailing 12 months and to calculate the sums separately but it is too slow. How do I optimize it?

I create all the indexes needed but it's still slow.

```
SELECT s.Activity, s.Sector, s.StartOfMonth, s.AmountMonth, SUM(salesLtd.Amount) [AmountLTD]
FROM (
    SELECT Activity, Sector, SUM(Amount) [AmountMonth], StartOfMonth
    FROM sales 
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, dateSale), 0) [StartOfMonth]) [forStart]
    GROUP BY Activity, Sector, StartOfMonth
) s
INNER JOIN sales salesLtd ON salesLtd.dateSale <= EOMONTH(s.StartOfMonth) 
    AND salesLtd.dateSale >= DATEADD(year, -1, s.StartOfMonth)
GROUP BY s.Activity, s.Sector, s.StartOfMonth, s.AmountMonth
```

Comment: Sample data and desires results would help.

Comment: Rather than a triangular join, a windowed `SUM` would likely be far faster. Indexes aren't going to help you here when you have clauses like `salesLtd.dateSale <= EOMONTH(s.StartOfMonth)` in the `ON`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming. you have values for each month, then just use a window function:

```
SELECT Activity, Sector, SUM(Amount) [AmountMonth], StartOfMonth,
       SUM(SUM(Amount)) OVER (PARTITION BY Activity, Sector ORDER BY MIN(dateSale) ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as amount_12monhth
FROM sales CROSS APPLY 
     (VALUES (DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(dateSale), MONTH(dateSale), 1)
     ) v([StartOfMonth])
GROUP BY Activity, Sector, StartOfMonth
```